# Accessing strings from a array of strings in GNU Octave

Tags: string, octave

How to access the whole elements `hello` and `ahoy` in Octave? Only the first character in each string is being printed.

```
octave:1> s = ["hello";"ahoy"]
s =

hello
ahoy 

octave:2> s(1)
ans = h
octave:3> s(2)
ans = a
```

Comment: I want to use this to automatically name multiple plots with the list of their names written in the array.

Comment: That syntax works in MATLAB only in which strings and characters are different. For Octave, use a cell array

Comment: just to add on to the explanation: you are using the newer 'string' class defined in Matlab 2017. Prior to that there were only character arrays in both Matlab and Octave., and they both would produce the output you report above.  Octave has not yet implemented a string class, as the new construct conflicts with some other design decisions that were made regarding char arrays. Hence, the 1st and 2nd elements of a char array are the 1st and 2nd characters, not the 1st and 2nd string.  try `class(s)` in both programs and note the difference. one will be a char and the other a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use cell arrays instead.

```
octave:1> s = { 'hello'; 'ahoy' };

octave:2> s{1}
ans = hello

octave:3> s{2}
ans = ahoy
```

See https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Cell-Arrays.html#Cell-Arrays

Answer (score 3):

Check the size and type of s to understand what's going on:

```
octave:5> size(s)
ans =

   2   5

octave:6> class(s)
ans = char
```

It's a 2x5 matrix of characters. To index, use matrix indexing. For example getting the first row:

```
octave:7> s(1,:)
ans = hello
```